# Fatal error: Call to undefined function ya_header_check()

Tags: wordpress

When I enter to the website, I see this error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function ya_header_check() in
>   /home/qachir/public_html/wp-content/themes/shoppystore3/header.php on
>   line 5

header.php Codes :

```
<?php get_template_part('templates/head'); ?>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
<div class="body-wrapper theme-clearfix">
<div class="body-wrapper-inner">
<?php ya_header_check(); ?>
```

How can I fix it?

Website url is http://www.qach.ir

Thanks.

Comment: we can't provide any solution without looking at code. first, update your question with the code from this file: `{your-website-folder/wp-content/themes/shoppystore3/header.php}`

Comment: I updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this line `<?php ya_header_check(); ?>` add this:

```
<?php if( function_exists('ya_header_check') ) ya_header_check(); ?>
```

This will prevent you to get the error provided.

Answer (score 0):

Shoppy Store theme comes with some dependencies. Check if you have installed and activated required plugins by shoppy store.

`Function ya_header_check()` is defined in one of them.

Checking if it exists or not is a proper way to write the code. I have no idea why the Plugin Author is not using it, but in your case, it removes the error and the content it provides, which I guess is the "Styled Header" which you set in "Advanced Options" section of theme setup.

Note: Don't use "Shoppy Store". It is a very ill-written theme.